# Modelling a power supply system

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, ac, impedance, phasor

I understand that for a RL based circuit connected to an AC supply, the impedance for the inductor is jωL and also I need to find the net resistance of the load model which I have derived to be (R*jωL)/(R+jωL). However I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find the net resistance of the load model which I have
>   derived to be (R*jωL)/(R+jωL). However I do not know how to proceed.

Multiply top and bottom by R-jwL. This is called "using the complex conjugate". It leaves a non complex number in the denominator and that's the beauty. The numerator will have j squared terms as well as j terms but then equate j squared to -1 because j is the square root of minus 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use excel to do filtering calculation (all circuits using R L or C).
For example with the function complex, imdiv, imsum, improduct, imabs,...
Your formula (R*jωL)/(R+jωL) gives an impedance identical than a circuit with your R in parallel with your L.